# SDL2: I Receive Segmentation Fault on Line 5, SDL_Surface

Tags: c++, c, gcc, sdl, sdl-2

When I run the program I get a segmentation fault on line 5, a SDL_Surface pointer that is getting the surface of the window. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
SDL_Window* window=NULL;
SDL_Surface* MainSurface=NULL;
SDL_Surface* ImageSurface=NULL;
void ifdebug(int pmbool,const char* str){
    if(pmbool==1){
        printf(str);
    }
}
void NewWindow(int x,int y,int pmbool){
    ifdebug(pmbool,"DEBUG^");
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Event MainEvent;
    int IsRunning=1;
    window=SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2: Window",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,x,y,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(window==NULL){
        ifdebug(pmbool,"WINDOW:ERROR<<");
        ifdebug(pmbool,SDL_GetError());
        ifdebug(pmbool,">>#\n");
        SDL_FreeSurface(ImageSurface);
        ImageSurface=NULL;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        window=NULL;
        SDL_Quit();
    }
    else{
        ifdebug(pmbool,"WINDOW:SUCCESS^");
    }
    MainSurface=SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    while(IsRunning){
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&MainEvent)!=0){
            if(MainEvent.type==SDL_QUIT){
                ifdebug(pmbool,"QUIT#\n");
                IsRunning=0;
                SDL_FreeSurface(ImageSurface);
                ImageSurface=NULL;
                SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                window=NULL;
                SDL_Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
void LoadImage(int pmbool,char* filename){
    ImageSurface=SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
    if(ImageSurface==NULL||filename==NULL){
        ifdebug(pmbool,"DEBUG^");
        ifdebug(pmbool,"LOADBMP:ERROR<<");
        ifdebug(pmbool,SDL_GetError());
        ifdebug(pmbool,">>#\n");
        SDL_FreeSurface(ImageSurface);
        ImageSurface=NULL;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        window=NULL;
        SDL_Quit();
    }
}
int main(int argc,char* args[]){
    NewWindow(600,400,1);
    LoadImage(1,"/home/vlad/Desktop/C-lang/BLU.bmp");
    SDL_BlitSurface(ImageSurface,NULL,MainSurface,NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
Line 5: 9029 (Core Dumped)
```

Does it have to do with the window?

Answer (score 0):

OP fixed it. Turns out it was the function that closes the window was preventing it from loading. Here's the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
SDL_Window* window=NULL;
SDL_Surface* MainSurface=NULL;
SDL_Surface* ImageSurface=NULL;
SDL_Event MainEvent;
void ifdebug(int pmbool,const char* str){
    if(pmbool==1){
        printf(str);
    }
}
void InitWindow(int x,int y,int pmbool){
    ifdebug(pmbool,"DEBUG^");
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window=SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2: Window",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,x,y,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(window==NULL){
        ifdebug(pmbool,"WINDOW:ERROR<<");
        ifdebug(pmbool,SDL_GetError());
        ifdebug(pmbool,">>#\n");
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        window=NULL;
        SDL_Quit();
    }
    else{
        ifdebug(pmbool,"WINDOW:SUCCESS^");
    }
}
void LoadImage(int pmbool,char* filename){
    MainSurface=SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    ImageSurface=SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
    if(ImageSurface==NULL){
        ifdebug(pmbool,"WINDOW:ERROR<<");
        ifdebug(pmbool,SDL_GetError());
        ifdebug(pmbool,">>#\n");
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        window=NULL;
        SDL_Quit();
    }
    SDL_BlitSurface(ImageSurface,NULL,MainSurface,NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
}
void InputGet(int pmbool){
    int IsRunning=1;
    while(IsRunning){
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&MainEvent)!=0){
            if(MainEvent.type==SDL_QUIT){
                ifdebug(pmbool,"QUIT#\n");
                IsRunning=0;
                SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                window=NULL;
                SDL_FreeSurface(ImageSurface);
                SDL_Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc,char* args[]){
    InitWindow(600,400,1);
    LoadImage(1,"/home/vlad/Desktop/C-lang/BLU.bmp");
    InputGet(1);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    return 0;
}
```